# In Solidity How to Get/Send Part of Ether Stored in msg.value?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, smart-contract-wallets

assuming i have the function:

```
// Fucntion that act like a wallet in which i deposit ether in it say 100ether        
function storeEth() public payable onlyOwner{ }
```

but then i want to withdraw or  send some of the ethers stored say 30 ether to another contract or address how to do so. I mean can i do something like

```
msg.value - 70; //or someting like that;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the suffix "ether".

Fore example:

`msg.value - 1 ether`

I suggest using the SafeMath library when using maths though.
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol